# Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: iphone

how to know my iphone device is registered or not  for applepushnotification service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking from a development perspective?  Push notification can be enabled on a per-app basis in the iPhone Developer Program Portal under the App ID section.  You need a valid and universally unique App ID.

If you're speaking from an accessibility standpoint for getting push notifications to your phone from a third party app, that is built into your phone and can be enabled/disabled from Settings on your iPhone.

Comment: as an developer i'm asking bcoz right now i use provisioning profile and certificate so that i get device token which i send to server but user doesn't follow these steps.how will i get device token of an particular user of an particular application of an particular device.